# How does React's useTransition avoid showing loading components?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-suspense

In the docs: https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useTransition#preventing-unwanted-loading-indicators

There's an example of a tab component that only shows up when it has finished loading all its data. Before it's finished, we still see the previously selected tab.

Something quirky is happening here, the `TabButtons` are aware of the new `tab` state and change their appearance, but in the rest of the JSX it seems we still work with the old value of `tab` - because we still see the previously selected tab, instead of no tab at all, or a spinner.

It seems that the `tab` state can have two values at the same time, in the same JSX statement.

See here, this is the code from the docs with a few things added to help in debugging:
https://codesandbox.io/s/how-does-usetransition-work-n2vc9x?file=/App.js

Comment: *It seems that the tab state can have two values at the same time, in the same JSX statement* - which statement exactly? I don't quite understand what is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Something quirky is happening here, the TabButtons are aware of the new tab state and change their appearance

Not all of the TabButtons are updating at this point, just the one in which you called `startTransition`. Notice that `About` is still in bold during this time; it's not yet a button.

What's happening is this:

1. You call `startTransition(() => { onClick(); });`, and since onClick sets state, this requests a low priority rerender of `App`
2. Before the low priority render, a high priority render happens just for the `TabButton` that called `startTransition`. During this render, It's still getting the old `isActive` prop which says it is not active, but `useTransition` returns `true` for `isPending`. As a result, it renders a `<b className="pending">`.
3. Now the low priority render starts, rendering from App and down. This render includes the new `tab` state and passes `isActive` props to the tabs based on that. However, because the data in `PostsTab` is not yet loaded, this render has to abort. It falls back to the suspense, but because of the transition, suspense will keep whatever is already mounted (it doesn't use the loading fallback).
4. Once the data is loaded another low priority render happens, and assuming this isn't interrupted the page updates with the new tab selected and the others deselected.

Comment: That made so much sense!! Wish I could accept this answer twice, thanks for explaining it in such detail!